# collapse specific nodes on load in d3 tree

Tags: jquery, d3.js, tree

Hi il update my question also il included a working jsfiddle to clearly see what i want to do.... http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/Ge58Q/15/

```
 nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("dy", 3.5)
   .attr("dx", 5.5)
   .attr("x", barWidth +20)
   .text(function(d) { return d.redirect_info; })
   .on("click", function(d){
        // using the value in d.redirect
       //search for the node with item_id equal to d.redirect
       //after finding that node input in update to draw



   });
```

above code i created a text  and append an onclick event...... if the text is click what i want is using the value of d.redirect  look for the nodes with the item_id equal to d.redirect then input that arrays in update function to draw the tree....... in my example if the text redirect_9_node_simple  is click it will draw the nodes from the ROOT UP TO THE NODE SIMPLE  and if the text redirect_13_node_alluring is click i want to draw tree from ROOT UP TO ALLURING NODE.        Note please scroll right because the text link is 20px to the right of rectangle

Comment: info please scroll the tree because the link text is 20px to the right of each node if a link exist   Thank YOu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide children of the node as follows:

```
function collapseSingle(node) {
    if (node.children) {
        node._children = node.children;
        node.children = null;
    }
}
```

Now, if you would like to show the childrens of node you could do this:

```
function expandSingle(node) {
    if (node._children) {
        node.children = node._children;
        node._children = null;
    }
}
```

So you show the children of node `2` - `cluster` and `graph` nodes after all children are hidden:

```
flare.children.forEach(collapse);
flare.children.forEach(expandSingle);
```

flare.children contains only one node `2` and its children will be visible (see line 37 and 47 http://jsfiddle.net/Ge58Q/10/). In this case, the line `flare.children.forEach(expandSingle)` could be replaced by `expandSingle(flare.children[0])` ... flare.children[0] is node `2`